# Pine-Script function

Tags: function, pine-script

I need some help to create a function as below, I want to get the sum of red volume in a defined period and the sum of green volume in this same period, to do the difference between both.

```
sumvolup(lenght) => 
    sumvolup = float(0)
    volwhengreen = valuewhen(close-open>=0, volume, 1)
    sumvolup := sum(volwhengreen, lenght)
    sumvolup
    
sumvoldown(lenght) => 
    sumvoldown = float(0)
    volwhenred = valuewhen(open-close>=0, volume, 1)
    sumvoldown := sum(volwhenred, lenght)
    sumvoldown
```

My issue is shown in the image below: when I try to check if my function works fine with a plotted char on my indicator, using `sumvolup(1)>sumvoldown(1)`, I I get plotted of the red bar volume.

[image: screenshot issue]

Comment: You seem to have code already. What does it do? Why is that wrong?

Comment: when I use plotchar and check with sumvolup(1)>sumvoldown(1), I see sup volume red bar plotted

Comment: I edited my post, I think it is clearer.

Comment: Yeah, (and maybe I'm wrong,) but "I get plotted of the red bar volume" still isn't that clear to me. Which bit is that in the screenshot? What should it look like instead?

Comment: because the red volume shouldn't be plotted because the sum of it is greater than the previous green volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to include a compilable code snippet when asking questions, including the plotting code, if you are having problems with it.

This may help you get on your way:

```
//@version=4
study("")
i_length = input(20)

// This is the equivalent of your snippet, in shorter form.
volUp = close >= open ? volume : 0
volDn = close <= open ? volume : 0
sumvolup   = sum(volUp, i_length)
sumvoldown = sum(volDn, i_length)

// This plots the information.
volIsUp = sumvolup > sumvoldown
plot(sumvolup, "sumvolup", color.green)
plot(sumvoldown, "sumvoldown", color.red)
plotchar(volIsUp[1], "volIsUp[1]", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Note that in here, where the conditions are equivalent to yours, you are counting volume twice when `close == open`:

```
volUp = close >= open ? volume : 0
volDn = close <= open ? volume : 0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you LucF, I understand the difference between logic "volUp = close >= open ? volume : 0 ..." and mine which didn't include "volume : 0". Works Fine !